# Matlab webbrowser to image

Tags: image, matlab, video, browser, capture

I would like to capture the screen of the Matlab webbrowser or IE with 30 or more fps. Has anyone an idea how I can do this? I was looking very long on the web but could not find a solution for that.
'getframe' seems to be to slow for this.

> ```
> web;
> while 1
> pause(0.033)  % For 30 fps 
>    pic = getframe(web);
>    imshow(pic)
> end
> ```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Why? Have you tried to do it completely without the pause?

Comment: Can you capture the frames first, save and show them later? That will increase the speed.

Comment: Have you tried using the [screen_record](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21216-screen-record) or [screenapture](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11363-screencapture) utilities?